# CakePHP 2/Javascript - Ajax Multi Upload - how can I force page load when the upload has finished?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2 alongside the wonderful Ajax Multi Upload plugin (I got it [here](https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload))

Basically the plugin creates a button which activates a file browser. When you choose a file the file uploads automatically. When that happens a little graphic appears on the page and the name of the file is there, so I know there must be somewhere I can hook into to add more javascript, but I'm new to JS and I haven't a clue where to look.

[This](https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload/blob/master/webroot/js/fileuploader.js) is the actual JS file where all the stuff happens..

I don't suppose anyone is familiar enough with this plugin/cake/javascript (and kind enough) to have a look and give me some clues.

Comment: I am not sure what the question/problem is here.  It seems you want to "hook into" the javascript., but it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry. Basically when the image uploads I want to add a .val to a form input. So I figure I need some way to know when the form has updated, for example the file name appears when the file uploads. So when that file name appears I'd like to add the file name as a value in a form input. Hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which actual javascript class you are using, but it looks like the various uploader classes all have `_onComplete` methods. I would guess this is where you would need to add some custom code to update the form.

Comment: After peering at the code, this appears to make use of [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com), which I maintain.  The documentation may give the question asker some clues, perhaps.

Comment: Hey, the _onComplete idea was good. I found somewhere I can hook into now I think.

Comment: @Ray - thanks for the tip and thanks for maintaining what looks to be a very handy wee plugin indeed (or part thereof) :) Thanks

Comment: @ray guys, I wonder. I can get an alert() to go off by placing it in one of the _onComplete functions in the main JS file (line 610). But how can I tell what the file name is? confused...

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox I would suggest you not modify ANY of the source code.  Instead, you can register your own `onComplete` callback handler.  Please see the [callbacks documentation](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/blob/master/docs/callbacks.md) in the Fine Uploader readme for more details.